# How can i verify excel data in multiple database(db2) using selenium webdriver?Is it possible or not?

Tags: selenium

Assume that I have uploaded an excel sheet using **import button** and in my excel sheet there are 100 columns and 100 columns are stored in different tables(DB2--store in 6 different tables). How can I verify that stored data are the same as my excel sheet's data?

Comment: selenium is the wrong tool for validating Excel data

Comment: I need to verify in my project. So what would be the right approach